# Why is std::sort complaining about a deleted copy ctor?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a simple class that holds a `std::string`:

```
class StringWrapper {
public:
    const std::string s;

    StringWrapper(const std::string s)
        : s(s) {}

    // We want this to be moveable but not copyable
    ~StringWrapper() = default;
    StringWrapper(const StringWrapper&) = delete;
    StringWrapper& operator=(const StringWrapper&) = delete;
    StringWrapper(StringWrapper&&) noexcept = default;
    StringWrapper& operator=(StringWrapper&&) = default;
};
```

Here we have tried to make the class moveable, but not copyable. I understand that a `const` member variable normally prevents a default move ctor from being generated, but here we try to explicitly generate it - and this at least compiles.

Now we try to sort a `std::vector<StringWrapper>` (the compare function is not important here):

```
std::vector<StringWrapper> strings;
std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(), [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return true; });
```

This fails to compile, but the error is very cryptic:

```
1>...\include\algorithm(7419,25): error C2280: 'StringWrapper &StringWrapper::operator =(const StringWrapper &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>...src\example.cpp(476): message : see declaration of 'StringWrapper::operator ='
1>...src\example.cpp(476,24): message : 'StringWrapper &StringWrapper::operator =(const StringWrapper &)': function was explicitly deleted
1>...\include\algorithm(7541): message : see reference to function template instantiation '_BidIt std::_Insertion_sort_unchecked<_RanIt,_Pr>(const _BidIt,const _BidIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=StringWrapper *,
1>            _RanIt=StringWrapper *,
1>            _Pr=myFunc::<lambda_8668e50965d967f7b587b72f59fcb0cf>
1>        ]
1>...\include\algorithm(7571): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Sort_unchecked<StringWrapper*,_Fn>(_RanIt,_RanIt,int,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Fn=myFunc::<lambda_8668e50965d967f7b587b72f59fcb0cf>,
1>            _RanIt=StringWrapper *,
1>            _Pr=myFunc::<lambda_8668e50965d967f7b587b72f59fcb0cf>
1>        ]
1>...src\example.cpp(488): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::sort<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,myFunc::<lambda_8668e50965d967f7b587b72f59fcb0cf>>(const _RanIt,const _RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=StringWrapper,
1>            _RanIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<StringWrapper>>>,
1>            _Pr=myFunc::<lambda_8668e50965d967f7b587b72f59fcb0cf>
1>        ]
1>...\include\algorithm(7422,28): error C2280: 'StringWrapper &StringWrapper::operator =(const StringWrapper &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>...src\example.cpp(476): message : see declaration of 'StringWrapper::operator ='
1>...src\example.cpp(476,24): message : 'StringWrapper &StringWrapper::operator =(const StringWrapper &)': function was explicitly deleted
1>...\include\algorithm(7425,24): error C2280: 'StringWrapper &StringWrapper::operator =(const StringWrapper &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>...src\example.cpp(476): message : see declaration of 'StringWrapper::operator ='
1>...src\example.cpp(476,24): message : 'StringWrapper &StringWrapper::operator =(const StringWrapper &)': function was explicitly deleted
```

Specifically, it suggests that `std::sort` is trying to reference the deleted copy ctor, but I don't know why that would be the case; I would expect `std::sort` to use only move operations.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: All the error messages refer to `operator=`. The won't generate an assignment operator when a class has `const` members.

Comment: Of course, "The won't" in my previous comment should be "The compiler won't".

Comment: `= default`: In this case, the default move operator is also deleted.

Comment: `StringWrapper` objects are not sortable, because they are not assignable, and not move-assignable.  You'll need to provide a move-assignable implementation.

Comment: Note that you'll also need an actual means of comparison, whether `operator<` or another function.

Comment: @Pete Becker & @Mooing Duck - Thanks! My IDE highlighted my copy ctor for some reason, but I see now that it is actually complaining about the assignment operator, and it makes sense that the default is deleted due to the `const` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been covered in the comments, but it's worth noting for posterity, the use of the `default` keyword does not guarantee that the compiler is always going to attempt to create a default implementation of a special member. This is (as usual) well-explained in the section on move assignment operators on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator).

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move assignment operator for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following is true:
>
> - T has a non-static data member that is `const`.

Compilers will also complain about this case as they do here. For example clang:

```
warning: explicitly defaulted move assignment operator is implicitly deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
    StringWrapper& operator=(StringWrapper&&) = default;
                   ^
note: move assignment operator of 'StringWrapper' is implicitly deleted because field 's' has no move assignment operator
    const std::string s;
```

Note that it's a warning and not an error, which is how you end up in this situation. In general it's best not to assume the `default` keyword allows you to bypass language restrictions.